# udpipe_accuracy() always gives the same error " The CoNLL-U line '....' does not contain 10 columns!"

Tags: r, nlp, udpipe

This is regarding the R package `udpipe` for NLP. I am using it to tokenize, tag, lemmatize and perform dependency parsing on text files.

I am not sure which template the `conllu` file is needed for the function

```
udpipe_accuracy
```

I loaded a CSV file of 10 columns but the error persists.

I could not search any questions on SO on this package and also there is no tag of udpipe.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You can give a sample of your problem and the expected output. May be, there would be another (may be better) package which can solve your problem.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, I am working on summarising large text documents. Before I can use any package like [textrank](https://github.com/bnosac/textrank/blob/master/vignettes/textrank.Rmd)  I need to convert the text into CoNLLU format. I guess that's the standard format for any NLP work on text.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set ? I think there might be another way to do it where you don't require CoNLLU format.

Comment: I guess I no longer need to run udpipe_accuracy, as I sorted out the fundamental problem of accurately creating a terminology file. But I now have a problem in ignoring page headers and footers in the text file imported for a pdf doc...as the CONLL-U format includes the headers also as sentences. I will close this question and open a new question if that is fine @ManishSaraswat

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`udpipe_accuracy` is used in combination with `udpipe_train`.
If you trained a custom udpipe model with udpipe_train based on data in conllu format, you can see how good it is by using udpipe_accuracy on hold-out conllu data which was not used to build the model.